# AWS EC2 instance connection timeout issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, connection, timeout

Here are the steps to indicating problems.  Successfully ssh AWS EC2 ubuntu instance using shh commands. Stopped/rebooted aws instance. Trying to shh login again with new Ip address and getting error Connection time out.

Answer (score -1):

Once you restarted your EC2 instance,public IP got changed.If you   want to stop instance's public ip to get change on every restart/termination then please use Elastic IP. Elastic Ips associated with account and not the instance so you can assign Elastic Ip on any instance you want.

Please use below command to connect:
 ssh ssh -v  -i primary_key.pem user@

Another option is to Log into your Amazon AWS Console and check running instance then copy Public DNS and try to connect with ssh. (ssk key is the same)